# Postfix send email through internet instead of sending through local for same-domain addresses

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I have multiple email servers for the same domain, one is a send-only postfix server and one is a email suite hosted by Zoho, but when I try to send an email to an address hosted by zoho it will try to send the mail to itself instead of using the internet

Here is my log

> to=service@mydomain.net, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "service")

I want to force postfix to send the mail so that it gets routed through the MX addresses set up in my DNS instead of looking for a local address

Comment: The list of domains that are to be delivered locally is configured in `mydestination`. If postfix is supposed to relay *all* messages for a domain elsewhere, that domain should typically not be listed there.

Comment: @anx where would mydestination be? I need to configure at least one domain for postfix to work right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your domain added to mydestination, it should be configured in /etc/postfix/main.cf

example:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, mailserver.domain.addres, domain.address, localhost
```

Comment: *Adding* to local destinations sounds like the opposite of the request in the question.

Comment: Yeah I need to send it through the internet and not locally